# Android - How to add action buttons inside the 360 vr video when using Google VrVideoView

Tags: android, video, google-cardboard, google-vr, vrvideoview

I am building an application to load the 360 vr video in Android.

For the video player, I use Google VrVideoView view. The problem here is I don't know how to add more buttons inside the video player like the attached image. And how to show the center-dot in the video player like that.

I want to use the Google Cardboard device to control my video by moving my head and touching the button on the cardboard when the center-dot at the button. I want to add some buttons like "next/play-pause/previous" the video.

Also, here is the document that I refer https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/vrview. But I did not find out the way of doing.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Thank!

[GoogleVR-View-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maH8n.jpg)

Comment: If you build the application in Unity, it provides with its own VideoPlayer which comes with basic controls like pause/play and scrub.

Comment: Thanks, @PrathamSehgal. I am building an app in Java/Android Studio. I am trying to figure out how to do it..